# How to simplify $\frac {\sin 3A - \cos 3A}{\sin A + \cos A} + 1$?

Tags: trigonometry

So I started by using $\sin 3A$ and $\cos 3A$ identities and then I added the lone $1$ to the trigonometric term. (Done in the picture below)

But after this I don't have any clue on how to proceed.

$$=\frac{3 \sin \theta-4 \sin ^{3} \theta-\left(4 \cos ^{3} \theta-\sin \theta\right)}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta} + 1$$
$$=\frac{3 \sin \theta-4\sin^{3} \theta-4 \cos ^{3} \theta+3 \cos \theta}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta} + 1$$
$$=\frac{3 \sin \theta-4 \sin ^{3} \theta-4 \cos ^{3} \theta+3 \cos \theta+\sin \theta+\cos \theta}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}$$
$$=\frac{4 \sin \theta-4 \sin ^{3} \theta-4 \cos ^{3} \theta+4 \cos \theta}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}$$
$$=\frac{4 \sin \theta+\cos \theta-\sin ^{3} \theta-\cos ^{3} \theta}
{\sin \theta+\cos \theta}
$$

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GMGs.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the comic relief.  Graphics instead of [using this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) + sideways to boot.

Comment: @YouKnowMe OP has taken LCM

Answer (score 4):

Recall the cube sum identity: $x^3+y^3 = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$

Continuing from where you left off:

\begin{align}&\quad4\frac {\sin\theta+\cos\theta-\sin^3\theta-\cos^3\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}\\
&=4-4\frac {\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}\\
&=4-4(\sin^2\theta - \sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta)\\
&=4-4(1-\frac12\sin2\theta)\\
&=2\sin2\theta
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sin3x-\cos3x}{\sin x+\cos x}+1=\frac{\sin3x+\sin x+\cos x-\cos3x}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{\sin(2x+x)+\sin (2x-x)+\cos (2x-x)-\cos(2x+x)}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{\sin2x\cos x+\sin x\cos2x+\sin2x\cos x-\sin x\cos 2x+\cos 2x\cos x+ \sin 2x\sin x-(\cos 2x\cos x- \sin 2x\sin x)}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{2 \sin2x\cos x +2 \sin 2x\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{2 \sin2x(\cos x +\sin x)}{\sin x+\cos x}=2\sin2x$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin3A-\cos3A$$
$$=\sqrt2\sin\left(3A-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

$$=\sqrt2\sin\left(3A+\dfrac{3\pi}4-\pi\right)$$

$$=-\sqrt2\sin3\left(A+\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

Similarly, $\sin A+\cos A=\sqrt2\sin(?)$

Finally for $\sin B\ne0,$ $$\dfrac{\sin3B}{\sin B}=\dfrac{\sin B(3-4\sin^2B)}{\sin B}=3-2(1-\cos2B)$$